# Filtering a DataFrame using user input

Tags: python, datetime, variables, dataframe, user-input

I am trying to use user input to filter data from a DataFrame.
I am very new to python and programming 
I have researched the topic but struggle to apply what I find to my project.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

CITY_DATA = { 'chicago': 'chicago.csv',
              'new york city': 'new_york_city.csv',
              'washington': 'washington.csv' }

def get_filters():

    print('\n\nHello! Let\'s explore some US bikeshare data!')

    while True:
        city = input(str('\nWhich city would you like to see data on?'
'New York City, Chicago, or Washington?\n ').lower())
        if city in ('washington', 'chicago', 'new york city'):
            break
        elif city == 'new york':
            city += ' city'
            break
        else:
            print('\n\nYour answer does not match any of the above options, please try again!\n')


    months = ['january', 'february',
            'march', 'april',
            'may', 'june', 'all']

    while True:
        month = input(str('\nWould you like to search by one of the following months?\nJanuary, February, March, April, May, June, or all?\n ').lower())
        if month in months:
            break
        else:
            print ('Your answer does not match any of the above options, please try again!\n')

    days = ['all', 'monday', 'tuesday',
    'wednesday, thursday, friday',
    'saturday', 'sunday']

    while True:
        day = input(str('\nWould you like to search by one of the following days?\nSunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, or all of them?\n' ).lower())
        if day in days:
            break
        else:
            print ('Your answer does not match any of the above options, please try again!\n')
    return city, month, day
    print('-'*40)
```

I am struggling with two main things for the moment.

the first is how to use the month & day variables as the column filter as the Excel file has a timestamp  with a number as the month. I have attempted to use DateTime.month as DateTime.weekday_name but I am not sure if I have applied it correctly or how to then use it to filter the columns.

```
def load_data(city, month, day):
    df = pd.read_csv(CITY_DATA[city])
    print ("printing {}...".format(city))
    df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
    df['Month'] = df['Month'].dt.month
    print('example month: {}'.format(df['Month']))
    df['Day of Week'] = df['Day of Week'].dt.weekday_name
    if month != 'all':
        df = df[df['Month'] == month[0]]
    if day != 'all':
        df = df[df['Day of Week'] == day[0]]       
    return df
```

the second thing I am struggling with is how to combine all the user input and produce the correct results.

```
def main():
    while True:
        city, month, day = get_filters()
        load_data(city, month, day)

        restart = input('\nWould you like to restart? Enter yes or no.\n')
        if restart.lower() != 'yes':
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What does your input file look like? And what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: my file is a .csv:

   Unnamed: 0           Start Time             End Time  Trip Duration  \
0     1423854  2017-06-23 15:09:32  2017-06-23 15:14:53            321
1      955915  2017-05-25 18:19:03  2017-05-25 18:45:53           1610


                   Start Station                   End Station   User Type  \
0           Wood St & Hubbard St       Damen Ave & Chicago Ave  Subscriber
1            Theater on the Lake  Sheffield Ave & Waveland Ave  Subscriber

   Gender  Birth Year
0    Male      1992.0
1  Female      1992.0

Comment: hi @lebenlechzer I am getting a Type~Error: 
'NoneType' object is not iterable
for city, month, day = get_filters()

Comment: First of all, you should remove the print statement that comes after the return (or put it in front of the return). Then try to print out city, month and day right before you return. It looks like the return value of your function is None.

Comment: @lebenlechzer you're right! return was in the wrong place, now I am getting an error message I had before: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bikeshare_3.py", line 165, in <module>
    main()
  File "bikeshare_3.py", line 153, in main
    load_data(city, month, day)
  File "bikeshare_3.py", line 73, in load_data
    df['Month'] = df['Month'].dt.month
KeyError: 'Month'

Comment: Then it seems that the column you are addressing is not called `Month`. If you look at [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) you'll see that the header is inferred by default from the first line in your CSV.

2 more things:
- these are simple errors that can easily be googled because they have been answered many times before.
- try to format your messages also in the comments (which makes it much easier to read them)